# How to access columns of aliased tables in nested queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query is not valid (postgre)SQL:

```
select x.name as child_name, parents.parent.name as parent_name
from X x
join (
  select child, parent 
  from X child
  join X parent on child.parent = parent.id
) parents on parents.child.id = x.id;
```

Is there any way to access the aliased tables from the joined nested query `parents` within the outer query?

I only know that I can select single columns in the nested query, and access these within the outer query, as below. But this is not what I want, as its cumbersome to explicitly export all columns.

```
select x.name as child_name, parents.parent_name as parent_name
from X x
join (
  select child.id as child_id, parent.name as parent_name
  from X child
  join X parent on child.parent = parent.id
) parents on parents.child_id = x.id;
```

Comment: _Columns_, not fields. And, yes, you can only access the subquery's select list items. (The from list is not known outside the sub-query.)

Comment: @jarlh Yes,I know that I have to `select` everything I want to export. I do this in the above query. What I really want to do is to export/select a whole aliased table (with all its columns). And then access its columns using the table alias from the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select x.name as child_name, parents.parent.name as parent_name
from X x inner join lateral
     (select child, parent 
      from X child join
           X parent
           on child.parent = parent.id
      where child.id = x.id
     ) parents;
```